# How to change view with Navigationlink with two conditions in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have 3 buttons in my view. I want to change view with navigationlink when 2 buttons are active. When I tap to tap1 and tap3 I want to go to ViewOne(), when I tap to tap2 and tap3 I want to ViewTwo() How can I do that ?

```
    @State var tap1 : Bool = false
    @State var tap2 : Bool = false
    @State var tap3 : Bool = false


    NavigationLink(destination: ViewOne(), isActive: $tap1, label: {
                            VStack{
                                Image("smile")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .renderingMode(.original)
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .frame(width: 150, height: 90)
                                
                                
                                Text("Fine")
                                    .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .thin))
                                    .padding(.bottom, 30)
                                
                            }
    
    
    NavigationLink(destination: ViewTwo(), isActive: $tap2) {
                        VStack{
                            Image("sad")
                                .resizable()
                                .renderingMode(.original)
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 150, height: 90)
                            
                            
                            Text("Bad")
                                .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .thin))
                                .padding(.bottom, 30)
                            
                        }
    
    NavigationLink(destination: ?(), isActive: $tap3) {
                        Text("Continue")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var tap1: Bool = false
    @State var tap2: Bool = false
    @State var isLinkActive: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                button1
                button2
                button3
            }
        }
    }

    var button1: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.tap1.toggle()
        }) {
            VStack {
                Image("smile")
                    .resizable()
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 90)

                Text("Fine")
                    .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .thin))
                    .padding(.bottom, 30)
            }
        }
        .background(tap1 ? Color.green : .clear)
    }

    var button2: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.tap2.toggle()
        }) {
            VStack {
                Image("sad")
                    .resizable()
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 90)

                Text("Bad")
                    .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .thin))
                    .padding(.bottom, 30)
            }
        }
        .background(tap2 ? Color.red : .clear)
    }

    var button3: some View {
        Button(action: {
            // make sure you set the link only when ready
            // what should happen if tap1 and tap2 are true?
            self.isLinkActive.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Continue")
        }
        .background(
            NavigationLink(destination: destinationView, isActive: $isLinkActive) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            .hidden()
        )
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    var destinationView: some View {
        if tap1 {
            Text("ViewOne")
        } else if tap2 {
            Text("ViewTwo")
        }
    }
}
```